# Matplot image (execute python from PHP) to png or sys.stdout

Tags: php, python, matplotlib, apache2

I'm trying to save matplot image by executing my_task.py from php-script at localhost.

my_task.py

```
    # do this before importing pylab or pyplot
    import matplotlib
    matplotlib.use('Agg')
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.plot([1,2,3])
    #fig.savefig('/var/www/html/test.png') # or relative path ('test.png') - Here I have an error - filename_or_obj = open(filename_or_obj, 'wb') IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/html/test.png'
    print "Hello<br>"
    import sys
    fig.savefig(sys.stdout, type='png')
```

If I'm trying fig.savefig(sys.stdout, type='png') - I'm getting ieroglighs, unreadable symbols, like:

```
    ‰PNG  IHDR Xљv‚psBIT|d€ pHYsaaЁ?§i IDATxњмЭ}lЦхЅяс'([О)xЊДrм™r°fБШкђўмЂШ ўђўЁґCV2n„QПшi9•№33ШЩЌ=ћeвNpЭI=‰їљ%PІЪiЎwм¤МЙ офtМЦ#ЗZЫ^ї?>gQn ґЧчєy>’&хZ/|5!qЇлуюѕ?#b±XI’$IЉѓ‘Q
    ђ$I’”>, ’$I’вЖ"I’$)n, ’$I’вЖ"I’$)n, ’$I’вЖ"I’$)n, ’$I’вЖ"I’$)n, ’$I’вЖ"I’$)n, ’$I’вЖ"I’$)n, ’$I’вЖ"I’$)n, ’$I’вЖ"I’$)n, ’$I’вЖ"I’$)n, ’$I’вЖ"I’$)n, ’$I’вЖ"I’$)n, ’$I’вЖ"I’$)n, ’$I’вЖ"I’$)n, ’$I’вЖ"I’$)n, ’$I’вЖ"I’$)n, ’$I’вЖ"I’$)n, 
    ’$I’вЖ"I’$)n, ’$I’вЖ"I’$)n, ’$I’вЖ"I’$)n, ’$I’вЖ"I’$)n, ’$I’вЖ"I’$)n, ’$I’вЖ"I’$)n, ’$I’вЖ"I’$)n, ’$I’вЖ"I’$)n, ’$I’вЖ"I’$)n, зрпяюп<рАЊ?ћїьЛїdмШ±ЬuЧ]јьтЛѓzясгЗyфСG№цЪkЙИИа®»овхЧ_жФ’$IRb»2к‰кдЙ“ЬpГ ,]є”їщ›
```

But If I try fig.savefig('/var/www/html/test.png') or relative path ('test.png') I have an error:

```
    filename_or_obj = open(filename_or_obj, 'wb')
    IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/html/test.png'
```

Please, help me with formatting to png or with rights to overcome permissions!
How to do it - right formatting to png or giving rights to overcome permissions?

Here is php-code:

```
  <?php
          $pytask = 'python py/my_task.py';
          echo "<br>" .$pytask,"<br>";
          $command = escapeshellcmd($pytask);
          $output = shell_exec($command);
          echo "<p>",$output,"</p>";
          echo '<p><img src="/PyPlots/test.png" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" alt="Куыгде"/></p>';

  ?>
```

***Addition:***
when I tried in php this:

```
          header("Content-type: image/png");
```

I received another error: 
***The image "http://localhost/test.php" cannot be displayed because it contains errors***

Answer (score -2):

This is a late reply, but hopefully it might still help someone.

See your code. You have 'commas' and not 'dots'

Change: `echo "<br>" .$pytask,"<br>";`
with: `echo "<br>" .$pytask."<br>";`

Change: `echo "<p>",$output,"</p>";`
with: `echo "<p>".$output."</p>";`

If you have access to your system, see errors (on apache) `/var/log/apache2/error.log`. It can help you.

Comment: The comma syntax is indeed possible (though inelegant IMHO) and the posters original problem is another one.